# /etc/sudoers is world writable for AIX7.1

Tags: sudo, aix

I have tried to alter the file /etc/sudoers in AIX7.1 to avoid prompting for password when using sudo , as I dont have enough right to visudo , so tried to add the write permission for me and then edit the file ,after I sudo chmod o+w /etc/sudoers , the problem occure as below :

sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

and now,I can not even sudo chmod the permission fo that file to 440 ,can anybody give some tips ? Appreciate .

Answer (score 1):

Do "su -l root", enter root's password, then chmod /etc/sudoers properly.

If You don't have root's password - You'll have to escalate it to the person having that password.

Comment: Thank you for your reply , obviously I dont have the Root password  ,escalate seems is the final solution ,thank you.